# Как верно написать?

Tags: грамматика

"разработан ряд программ" или "разработаны ряд программ"; "разработан ряд техник" или "разработаны ряд техник"?

Comment: Как верно написать: "куплена пачка колготок" или "куплены пачка колготок"?

Answer (score 2):

В приведенных фразах сказуемое, выраженное кратким причастием, согласуется со словом "ряд", то есть употребляется в единственном числе.

Comment: В продолжение мысли: если бы было: "разработаны программы", то множественное.